# Customize the C++ scintilla lexer

Tags: c++, notepad++, scintilla

Where can I tell scintilla to recognize different keyword sets ? I want to color them differently, just like notepad++ does.

Comment: Look at the Notepad++ source code.  It uses Scintilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well scintilla behaviours are quite hard-coded, so it's quite delicate to tweak a lexer. I gave up using Qscintilla or scintilla, and switched to TextAdept, which use LUA to build lexers.

The mac version seemsto have some speed issues, but I guess it will be fixed (or not) when it will come as a portable .app (let us pray).

Anyways, I'm quite sad that I wasn't able to make a good C++ editor like I wanted, it seems I wanted too many features that existing libs can offer but require some work, which I don't have time for. I'm quite disappointed concerning scintilla, it's a good lib, but the code looks a little bloated, I guess doing a language-agnostic lexer and subclass it would seem like a better idea, but I won't try to redesign what has already been done.

Answer (score 1):

use `SCI_SETKEYWORDS`

Comment: an example of how to use SCI_SETKEYWORDS exists at: scintilla/cocoa/ScintillaTest/AppController.mm

Comment: You're kind, but I'm just doing C++.